# Non-reproducible installation with npm

Tags: javascript, npm

I have to maintain a project that uses `npm` but I don't know much about it.

More specifically, we have 2 shared JS libraries and a bunch of page-specific code (that rely on the libraries) and we use `npm` and `rollup` to produce bundles of the page-specific code that is served. The libraries have a `package.json` file for their dependencies (D3.js, jQuery, etc.). The pages also have a `package.json` file to include the libraries (with `file:path/to/file`) and other dependencies.

The depencies are organized like this:

```
lib1/
lib2/
  requires "file:../lib1"
plugins/
  page1/
    requires "file:../../lib2"
  page2/
    requires "file:../../lib2"
```

In a first attempt, we have comited the `package-lock.json` and wrote a script that basically jumps in `lib1` to run `npm install` and `rollup`, then does the same in `lib2` (as it depends on `lib1`) and then does the same for every page.

While this sometimes work, we experience random failures like:

```
npm ERR! path /path/to/lib2/node_modules/.staging/@types/estree-39f5a558
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/path/to/lib2/node_modules/.staging/@types/estree-39f5a558' -> '/path/to/lib1/node_modules/@types/estree'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

The directory `/path/to/lib1/node_modules/@types/estree` exists.

This sometimes fail in `lib2` and sometimes in a page.

Removing the `package-lock.json` didn't help. Using `shrinkwrap` didn't help too.

Does anybody know what is going wrong ?

Comment: I'd like to see the dependency statement of package "estree" in package.json

Comment: `estree` is not in any of my `package.json`. It's installed by some dependencies (`esdoc` I guess). Note that I edited the message since it contained some local path. What puzzle me is that `npm` tries to install packages from `lib1` into `lib2`. The path in `lib1` exists by the way.

Comment: As per this [link](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/arcs/pull/2770), this looks like a bug in `npm`, and is fixed in v6.9.0. Try upgrade your `npm` to see if pb goes away.

Comment: Thanks for the link (I think I hit some of those pages but I didn't understand the solution). `npm` v6.9.0 is not yet in Fedora (our distro) and it's not yet in `nodejs`. Do you know if `sudo npm install npm -g` is safe ?

Comment: Lol, as of security, theoretically nothing is guaranteed in js community :facepalm:. But joke aside yeah, you can practically consider `npm` safe. Need to have some faith in the de facto package manager for one of the largest community.

Comment: @hackape Thanks for your help. I have tried with `npm` v6.9.0 without success. I will try to create a minimal example and contact the npm community.